# Use the next possible primary key on auto_increment column after deleting one or more row

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a table with a primary key, auto_increment ID column. When I delete the row with the highest ID, for instance ID 100, I want to use that ID 100 for a new row only using a mysql trigger. How do I do that?

*When I delete, for instance ID 1 AND the highest ID is 100, I don't want to use ID 1 again.*

I do the delete and insert statement with different PHP calls.

Comment: Why? If you need this, then ID isn't a surrogate key, and so it isn't an auto_increment column. If there are rules to what the next number could be (any other than unique in the table), then you should implement your own mechanism as per the answer from @arnoughhgz, not use the built in auto_increment feature

Comment: Of course I don't need the field to be an auto_increment, thanks for that, but the ID column has a unique key and I want always the lowest possible ID after the current highest ID in the table.

Comment: Fair enough, still don't know why though. In my experince the desire to do this sort of thing, usually means a surrogate key is being exposed, and that's a bad idea unless you are very lucky.

Comment: I now use the auto increment again, because I needed the `last_isert_id()` method from mysql. I don't do a trigger before insert, I do a procedure on delete. (see my last answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11742883/1065251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the right solution for my problem. Thanks to all your suggestions en criticism. Instead of using a trigger, I now use a procedure (thanks for the idea @shubhansh).

This is the create statement for the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `[DATABASE]`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `[PROCEDURE NAME]`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `[PROCEDURE NAME]`(deleteID INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INTEGER;

    SET @deleteRow = CONCAT('delete from `[TABLE NAME]` WHERE ID = ', deleteID);
    PREPARE a FROM @deleteRow;
    EXECUTE a;

    SET i = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ID), 0) FROM `[TABLE NAME]`);
    SET @alterTable = CONCAT('alter table `[TABLE NAME]` auto_increment = ',(i+1));
    PREPARE b FROM @alterTable;
    EXECUTE b;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I can delete and alter one table in one PHP statement and it is save because the procedure locks the table.

Answer (score 1):

You should set AUTO_INCREMENT table option, e.g. -

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 100;

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

...then insert new records.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (NULL); --> will add 100
```

Comment: When only using mysql, this will work. I want to run it from PHP, so a trigger is less programming in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trigger (with drop / create statement):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_name`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE inc_val INT;
    SET inc_val := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ID), 0)+1 FROM table_name)
    ;
    SET NEW.ID = inc_val
    ;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Need to set it to something if the table is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I already was using the table for a while, so I didn't have a empty table for this problem. But I have changed my solution (`MAX(ID)+1` ===> `IFNULL(MAX(ID), 0)+1`)

Comment: What happens if two rows are inserted at once? Don't they get the same ID perhaps? And what happens with two concurrent insertions? Shouldn't the trigger lock `'table_name'` table?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change `auto_increment` value using `alter table`. Since, checking each time at insert might lead to performance issues. So I thought its better to put trigger when deletion is done.

I tried this and came to conclusion that `Alter table` can't be applied in triggers. And  Doing only `"Alter table"` to change `auto_increment` is solution this way, So this approach can't be taken.

MySQL gives error "Explicit/Implicit Commits are not allowed in Trigger".

I suggest you to create a stored procedure and then call it when ever you are deleting from table. I guess you always know where you are deleting(so seems to be feasible).

The procedure is as follows:

---

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `database_name`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `new_max`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_max`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    SET i = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table_name`);
    SET @ddl = CONCAT('alter table `table_name` auto_increment = ',(i+1));
    PREPARE STMT FROM @ddl;
    EXECUTE STMT;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And you will be calling it as `call new_max();`

With stored procedure, you need not do much of programming, just add simple line in your code after delete command is fired and it will work as you want. Hope it helps....