# MySQL auto-increment column - cannot re-use numbers after deleting records

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an auto-increment integer field "ID". Let's say there's a hundred records in it, and I delete records 91 - 100. The next record I create I'd expect the ID field to be 91, but it isn't, it's 101.
Is there any way to get around this? Thanks guys.

Comment: This isn't meant to be rude, but; why do you expect it to be 91? If you remove records 10 to 18, do you expect the next inserted record to have id 10? =)

Comment: Unless you have a very pressing reason, you should almost never alter the auto increment process on a live database.  It's unfortunately, just not the way auto increment fields (in MySQL) are meant to work.

Comment: You can create a `procedure` on your database. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11739793/1065251

This will delete your record and set the auto_increment to the highest possible value.

You won't be able to fill the holes as @J.Steen metioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually set [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)  after `delete` operation as:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 91;
```

Comment: @J Steen - yes, but only if there are no higher numbered records in the table.

Comment: yes otherwise you will have to mention values for `id`  manually by finding holes while inserting the new data. Hope this helps! Don't forget to accept the best answer!

Comment: Omesh, how do I accept it? I'm quite new on here and I can't see anything that might be "accept".

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the auto-imcrement from your table and set the id manually every time you are inserting something

```
@maxid = select max(id) from your_table
insert into your_table (id) values (@maxid+1)
```