# Serial number updation and database

Tags: php, database, wamp

I have inserted serail_number column in database. When i delete the user, then the serial number doesn't **update**. Before deletion,column values:
 1
 2
 3
 4 and so on. 
After deletion,column values::: 
 1
 3
 4
 and so on..
I want it to be like: after deletion,column values:.. 
 1
 2
 3
 What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure on your database. See [stackoverflow.com/q/11739793/1065251](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11739793/1065251) This will delete your record and set the auto_increment to the highest possible value.